# Plotting Histogram of Gray image

Tags: python, matplotlib

I am trying to figure out a way to find the histogram of a grayscale image. So first i found the average weight of the image then output it as a grayscale, fine. I'm just baffled by plotting the gray image into a histogram. Can someone help me figure out how to plot the grayscale image into a histogram?

```
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as py
from PIL import Image as im
from scipy import misc


img = misc.imread("Zpicture.jpg")

def weightedAverage(pixel): ## function to calculate
    return 0.299*pixel[0] + 0.587*pixel[1] + 0.114*pixel[2]

grey = np.zeros((img.shape[0], img.shape[1])) # init 2D numpy array
# get row number
for rownum in range(len(img)):
 for colnum in range(len(img[rownum])):
  grey[rownum][colnum] = weightedAverage(img[rownum][colnum])


 py.imshow(grey, cmap = py.matplotlib.cm.Greys_r)
 py.show()
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you are looking for `plt.hist(grey)`. Note that the usual convention is import `matplotlib.pyplot` as `plt`. It is good to stick to commonly used styles!

Lastly, your image conversion code can be simplified as:

```
grey = 0.299*img[:,:,0] + 0.587*img[:,:,0] + 0.114*img[:,:,0]
```

Comment: Hey @VBB thanks for the feedback, is there a way to create bins for the histogram?

Comment: `bins = 30` would make 30 bins. `bins = [1,2,3,4]` (or bins = some_numpy_array) would use those as bin boundaries. Note that if you give bins=[1,2,3,4] then you get 3 bins (i.e. n-1 bins for n boundaries)

Comment: See http://matplotlib.org/1.4.2/api/pyplot_api.html#matplotlib.pyplot.hist for more details

Answer (score 0):

Consider using Seaborn. It is a wrapper of Matplotlib that offers a slightly more streamlined API.

```
import seaborn as sn

sn.distplot(grey, bins=100, kde=False)
sn.plt.show()
```

Check the documentation for keyword arguments. `kde` set to `True` would perform a KDE fit of the histogram.

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve this by using [matplotlib.pyplot.hist](https://matplotlib.org/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.pyplot.hist.html) and [numpy.ndarray.ravel()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.ndarray.ravel.html)

```
from matplotlib import pyplot as plt

gray_image = cv2.imread("Zpicture.jpg", cv2.IMREAD_GRAYSCALE)
plt.hist(gray_image .ravel(), bins=255)
plt.show()
```

**Note:** I'm using numpy-v1.15

Answer (score 0):

**You can Use seaborn Library to draw a Histogram of grayscale or RGB channels like that**

**In case The image RGB Using Seaborn**

```
import seaborn as sns
blue_bricks = cv2.imread('../DATA/bricks.jpg') #incase the image RGB
    show_bricks = cv2.cvtColor(blue_bricks, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)   
     a=show_bricks[:,:,0] #need to be flatten to be showen in histplot 
        z=a.reshape(1,-1) #flatten the image
        sns.histplot(np.squeeze(z))
```

**For GrayScale Image Using Seaborn**

```
blue_bricks = cv2.imread('../DATA/bricks.jpg')
     a=show_bricks[:,:] 
        z=a.reshape(1,-1) #flatten the image
        sns.histplot(np.squeeze(z))
```

**Using OpenCv**

```
 import cv2
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    %matplotlib inline
    hist_values = cv2.calcHist([dark_horse],channels=[0],mask=None,histSize=[256],ranges=[0,256])
    plt.plot(hist_values)
```